# disable function using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to disable a javascript function (`dialogs()`) using jQuery.

What I thought to do was:

- Wrap the function in a span: `"<span class = 'auto'>" + dialogs(i,0); + "</span>"`
- If the checkbox is checked, do: (this `if` statement is in `$(document).ready(function(){`)

  ```
  if ($("#autodialog").is(":checked")) {
     $(".auto").remove(); }
  ```

But this doesn't seem to be working.

Any thoughts?

Comment: @Ben What is confusing you? I want to allow users to decide whether a certain javascript function is run... so I'm giving them a checkbox... when it's checked, it should comment out the function from running (function is a recursive function within a function)

Comment: I guess the whole "disabling a javascript function". nvm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make your `dialogs` methods to handle a extra parameter `isEnabled`, a boolean dataType.

```
function dialogs(i,0,isEnabled) {
 if(isEnabled) {
  //Todos
 }
}
```

then make it to look like this

```
if ($("#autodialog").is(":checked")) {
   dialogs('i',0,false);  //I'm not sure about the values of parameter i
    }
```

So there is no need of using `span` tag as a wrapper.

Hope you understand.

Comment: @Growler I'm glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 1):

A little more context would be helpful (do you have a jsfiddle we can see?)

I think you may be confusing the Javascript function and the value returned from the function. Are you trying to remove a string of HTML generated by the dialogs() function, or are you trying to remove the actual dialogs function itself?

If you want to disable the dialogs function:

```
<script>
   function getDialogs(a,b) {
      // ...
   }

   var dialogs = getDialogs; // Make dialogs refer to getDialogs
</script>
```

Elsewhere you'll have something like:

```
<script>
   if ( $("#autodialog").is(":checked") ) {
      dialogs = function __noop__() {};
   } else {
      dialogs = getDialogs;
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you will have to add a click handler to the checkbox

```
 $("#autodialog").click(function(){
 if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
   dialogs(i,no,false); }
else
  dialogs(i,no,true); 
});


function dialogs(i,no,flag){
if(!flag)
 {event.preventDefault();return flag;}
else{
  ......//your working code}
}
```

Comment: Thought I could just allow the `document.ready` to run through that if statement without a handler

Comment: @Growler does you checkbox comes checked when the docuement load? no right?! so that if condition won't be true

Comment: Also, can I just disable the function somehow without removing it? If the user unchecks the box, I'd like the function to run again... so I don't thin removing it would be good

Comment: @Growler the updated code allows you to rewrite the function call inside the span, the function takes a boolean flag which if true will execute your function else will return false

Comment: You're making it so complicated.  OP is using `span` tag inorder to disable the `dialogs` method.

Comment: @user1671639 oh yea, you are right, forgot what the purpose of span was